# Can we add UiElements inside CoreWindowDialog?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winrt-xaml

I need a control like message box or corewindowDialog to get some details from user. How can I add UiElements inside CoreWidndowDialog. Help me!

Comment: 1) Please show us some code. 2) Please give more details.

Comment: I am looking for a control to add some textbox fields inside the control. the control should have the behavior of message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the popup control to display the textbox and other controls similar to message box concepts

Answer (score 0):

There are some open source alternatives that provide a custom dialog as well.  http://winrtxamltoolkit.com and the CustomDialog